# Windows 10 Upgrade for many PCs

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am supposed to upgrade about 70 PCs from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (via the free method of Windows Update). The thing is, that the internet is slow, and when I am trying to download about 3 Windows 10s at the same time it is very slow, I mean like really slow (a few % of progress every hour).

My question is if there actually is a method to download the installation file just one time and then copy it to all PCs and just type in the License Key of Windows 7 into the Windows 10 installation on every single PC.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-media-creation-tool-create-installation-media-upgrade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I have had so many issues with in place upgrades that I have lost count. That being said (assuming you have a list of the Windows 7 Product Keys) I would recommend setting a PXE server up (Windows Deployment Services would be best). Backup the data you need and then mass push a fresh Windows 10 Image to the network(multicast). Afterwards import the data and activate Windows 10 with the Windows 7 keys. MAKE SURE TO USE THE SAME VERSION, see below for version correspondence. By using WDS you also get the added benefit of a single image download as well as all you have to do is pxe boot the laptops / desktops and then they all install at once.

**Home Premium = Home**

**Pro / Ultimate = Pro**

**Enterprise = Enterprise**

Source:

Personal Experience and Microsoft

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10

Comment: If I may ask: if I'll make a Win 10 Installation DVD (out of downloaded ISO) and then when prompted I'll type in the License Key of the current Windows 7 machine, will it work and activate itself?

Comment: If the media your using is the new Apirl 2016 1511 media than yes if not use a key from here <https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396>, and then change it after Windows 10 installs, as I don't think you can skip the key entry process on the Retail media. (Sorry I don't know, I have msdn and their media is different.)

Comment: Both Retail and VL provide the option to skip key during install.

Comment: Then skip the product key entry and enter it and activate the OS after you have it booted up and activated.

Comment: Please remember to mark it as an answer if my solution helped you.